# how to restrict input decimal values upto 3 in UI5

Tags: javascript, sapui5

I want to restrict the number of decimal upto 3 using `sap.m.Input`.
I'm trying this, but it seems to work as a *string*.

```
value = "{ path: 'config>TenantInc', type: 'sap.ui.model.type.Float', formatOptions: { maxFractionDigits: 3 } }"
```

Comment: What type is your 'config>TenantInc' property?

Comment: Can you add the screenshots of the error/misbehavior ? It works for me.

Comment: You might want to use `StepInput` instead of just `Input`. Check out this answer: [https://stackoverflow.com/a/47308880/5846045](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47308880/5846045)

Answer (score 0):

**My way to do using formatter**

```
value = "{ path: 'config>TenantInc', formatter: 'formatterPath.decimal'}"
```

> Formatter function below

```
    decimal : function(d){
        return parseFloat(d).toFixed(2);// if value is string
        // if number use below statement
        // return d.toFixed(2)
    }
```

Comment: But what if the user edits the input? Afaik using formatters doesn't work with two way binding.

Comment: then on liveChange event he should format the value again